# Flutter: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have an app and want to view the username of the ad creator but I had a little problem when I run it , I receive this error:

```
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget. 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 298 pos 10: 'data != null'

The relevant error-causing widget was:    AdView file:///Users/ahmedhussain/Downloads/khamsat/Client%20Apps/HPX-KSA/hpx_ksa/lib/Screens/custom_ad_tile.dart:23:79 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:298:10)
#3      _AdViewState.build (package:hpxksa/Screens/ad_view.dart:134:34)
```

Although I checked the database and there is data already there inside a document and if I changed the value to any other value in document it works properly.

Here is my code:

```
class AdView extends StatefulWidget {

  final AdModel adModel;
  final String submittedStr;

  AdView({this.adModel, this.submittedStr});

  @override
  _AdViewState createState() => _AdViewState();
}

return StreamProvider<List<AdModel>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().ads,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                          child: Text(widget.adModel.username  , style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),),
                          onTap: (){},
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          child: Text(widget.adModel.location, style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),),
                          onTap: (){},
                        ),
```

Here AdModel class:

```
class AdModel{
  String category;
  String location;
  String adName;
  String adImage;
  String userId;
  String username;

  AdModel({
    this.category,
    this.location,
    this.adName,
    this.adImage,
    this.userId,
    this.username,
});
```

and here is how I pass AdModel through AdView:

```
class CustomAdTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final AdModel adModel;

  CustomAdTile({this.adModel});

  @override
  _CustomAdTileState createState() => _CustomAdTileState();
}

class _CustomAdTileState extends State<CustomAdTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          print('card pressed');
          Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AdView(adModel: widget.adModel,)));
    },
```

Here ia AdList where AdModel is created and used in Provider:

```
  class _AdsListState extends State<AdsList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final ads = Provider.of<List<AdModel>>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount:(ads == null) ? 0 :  ads.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return
            CustomAdTile(adModel: ads[index],);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use something like that: ```Text(widget?.adModel?.username ?? "Undefined")```

Answer (score 0):

You can print `widget.adModel.username` to see if it's really `null` and you should also do `null check` like this `widget?.adModel?.username ?? 'value is null'`

```dart
return StreamProvider<List<AdModel>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().ads,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                          child: Text(widget?.adModel?.username ?? 'username is null' , style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),),
                          onTap: (){},
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          child: Text(widget?.adModel?.location ?? 'location is null', style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),),
                          onTap: (){},
                        ),
```

Comment: you printed `widget.adModel.username` and it showed a value or you printed `widget.adModel`. which of them did you print?

Comment: I printed widget.adModel.username and it shows value

Comment: That means that `widget.adModel.username` is null then. something is wrong with your model

Answer (score 0):

widget.adModel not giving you updated values that you are getting default value of variable as null

```
Text(widget.adModel.username?? ""  , style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),),

Text(widget.adModel.location?? "", style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because because widget.adModel.username is null.  U can get around that error by doing this

```
Text('${widget.adModel.username}' ?? 'Username not available' , style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),

Text('${widget.adModel.location}' ?? 'Location not available', style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),
```

?? this basically means if the first is null then use second string

Comment: can your share the Admodel class structure, also the the code where you are passing those parameters

Comment: I edited the code try using that and see if it works

Comment: I added the AdModel and how I pass it and I tried your modified code but did not work also

Comment: can you show me the code where you created the admodel object and passed values to the constructor

Comment: I added how I used adModel as a list with provider